# If and else block is executed during spring method annotated as Transactional

Tags: spring, transactional, modelandview

When I go to /confirmation-account link, in tomcat console I can see that if and else block is also executed. I can see:

print from ColorConsoleHelper.getGreenLog("loginView") and from  ColorConsoleHelper.getGreenLog("confirmationAccountView")

This is really strange behavior. Why?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/confirmation-account", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 @Transactional
 public ModelAndView displayConfirmationAccountPage(ModelAndView modelAndView,  @RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams) {

    final int ACTIVE_USER   = 1;

    // find the user associated with the confirmation token
    UserEntity userEntity = userService.findUserByConfirmationToken(requestParams.get("token"));

    // this should always be non-null but we check just in case
    if (userEntity!=null) {

        // set the confirmation token to null so it cannot be used again
        userEntity.setConfirmationToken(null);

        // set enabled user
        userEntity.setEnabled(ACTIVE_USER);

        // save data: (token to null and active user)
        saveAll(userEntity.getTrainings());

        /*
            RedirectAttributes won't work with ModelAndView but returning a string from the redirecting handler method works.
         */

        modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "Konto zostało pomyślnie aktywowane!");
        modelAndView.setViewName("loginView");
        ColorConsoleHelper.getGreenLog("loginView");

    } else {

        ColorConsoleHelper.getGreenLog("confirmationAccountView");
        modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage", "Link jest nieprawidłowy...");
        modelAndView.setViewName("confirmationAccountView");
    }

    return modelAndView;
}


public void saveAll(List<TrainingUserEntity> trainingUserEntityList) {
    for ( TrainingUserEntity trainingUserEntity : trainingUserEntityList) {
        entityManagerService.mergeUsingPersistenceUnitB(trainingUserEntity);
    }
}

public void mergeUsingPersistenceUnitB(Object object) {
     EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManagerPersistenceUnitB();
     EntityTransaction tx        = null;
     try {
         tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
         tx.begin();
         entityManager.merge(object);
         tx.commit();
     } 
     catch (RuntimeException e) {
         if ( tx != null && tx.isActive() ) tx.rollback();
         throw e; // or display error message
     }
     finally {
         entityManager.close();
     }
 }
```

Comment: please share saveAll() method also

Comment: I added this to code.

Comment: and the code `entityManagerService.mergeUsingPersistenceUnitB` also

Comment: I added to code, maybe it is dirty read?

Comment: If you see both logs, it can only mean that the method is being executed twice (or that the deployed code isn't the one you're showing us, or that the same logs are printed from elsewhere). Add logs in the method (before the if block), use your debugger, look at your network panel in the browser dev tools, etc.

Comment: `if ( tx != null && tx.isActive() ) tx.rollback();` does it go here? can you debug on your end

Comment: @JB Nizet - I checked and indeed this method is invoke twice for the first time when I open the link. But why?

Answer (score 0):

Below solution & explanation:

Because of /confirmation-account link is invoke twice, what is caused by dynamic proxy and @Transactional method annotated in controller It is mandatory to check how many displayConfirmationAccountPage method is invoked. It is workaround.

What do you think it is good or not to annotated @Transactional controller method?